# Clarify proof that $E(g(x))={\int}g(x)f(x)dx$

Tags: probability, integration, derivatives, means

I got stuck in a specific point in a proof for that $E(g(x))={\int}g(x)f(g(x))dx={\int}g(x)f(x)dx$ . Could you help?

Teacher's proof:

Let $Y=g(x)$.

$E(Y) = {\int}yf(y)dy = {\int}y(\frac{F(y)d}{dy})dy = {\int}y(F_x(g^{-1}(y)){\frac{d}{dy}})$

$[Since: F_y(y) = P(Y<y) = P(g(x) < y) = P(X < g^{-1}(y))= F_x(g^{-1}(y))]$

Now That leads to:

$={\int}y\frac{d}{dy}({\int\limits_{}^{x=g^{-1}(y)}}f_x(t)dt)dy$

-Why?

Why is ${\int}y(F_x(g^{-1}(y)){\frac{d}{dy}})$ = ${\int}y\frac{d}{dy}({\int\limits_{}^{x=g^{-1}(y)}}f_x(t)dt)dy$ ?

I understand that there is a chain rule: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule ... But I cannot justify that equalty. How can I prove that part?

Comment: $E(g(x))={\int}g(x)f(x)dx\ne{\int}g(x)f(g(x))dx$

Comment: What? Why? Could you explain where am I wrong? Like, we set $Y$ to be $g(x)$,  hence they are prooving the same thing. No?

Comment: [LOTUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician)

Comment: It doesn't say anything about that those two I and you had mentioned should be inequal. Plus this equality you mention is in fact wrong, is the definition. Unless I miss something.

Comment: Like, it's true by definition.

Comment: Oh, yes perhaps $f(g(x))$ is confusing. Consider it $f_2(g(x))$.

Comment: You need to be more careful with the notation. $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ are the same function evaluated in different values of the variable, or different functions? If the latter, you should add some subindex to identify them, eg $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$

Comment: +1 @leonbloy When there are several densities involved, always use indices. And it's not $E(g(x))$ but $E(g(X))$, where $X$ is a random variable. I didn't pay attention above when I copy/pasted from the question.

Comment: Thanks, thank you! I will pay attention from now on to Random Variables vs Just Variables.

Comment: you are using the same letter $f$ for two different functions in the first formula on your text